# Child ScrollView does not scroll when parent ScrollView stops scrolling

Tags: react-native, scroll, scrollview, react-native-flatlist, flatlist

[App with scroll](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ZkdA.png)

In the image I have drawn you can see two areas, the yellow one is a ScrollView, and the red one is a flatlist.
When I scroll from the red zone, I want the tabs to go up to the header, and once they touch the header, start scrolling the red zone of FlatList.
To do this, when the tabs touch the header I set the scrollEnabled from the yellow zone to false, the problem is that the red zone doesn't scroll until I stop pressing and press again.

The behavior I want it to have is similar to the instagram profile, where there are some tabs and then a list of photos, when the tabs touch the header, you can continue scrolling from the images.

Answer (score 0):

I'll add a few options

1. First one is a snack, which again uses parent and child scrollviews
   [Collapsible Header Tabs Snack](https://snack.expo.io/@mattx/collapsible-header-tabs)

Problems: This has issues on Android. the scroll stutters on android while both parent and child scrollviews are scrolling.

2. Second is github repo [React-Native-Collapsing-TabView](https://github.com/developerashish01/React-Native-Collapsing-TabView)

Problems: if one of the tab is scrolled and you go to another tab then there will white space on top.[issue](https://github.com/developerashish01/React-Native-Collapsing-TabView/issues/2#issue-611082327)

3. Using Native Base.

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import {Animated, Dimensions, Platform, Text, TouchableOpacity, View} from "react-native";
import {Body, Header, List, ListItem as Item, ScrollableTab, Tab, TabHeading, Tabs, Title} from "native-base";
import LinearGradient from "react-native-linear-gradient";

const {width: SCREEN_WIDTH} = Dimensions.get("window");
const IMAGE_HEIGHT = 250;
const HEADER_HEIGHT = Platform.OS === "ios" ? 64 : 50;
const SCROLL_HEIGHT = IMAGE_HEIGHT - HEADER_HEIGHT;
const THEME_COLOR = "rgba(85,186,255, 1)";
const FADED_THEME_COLOR = "rgba(85,186,255, 0.8)";

export default class ParallaxDemo extends Component {
  nScroll = new Animated.Value(0);
  scroll = new Animated.Value(0);
  textColor = this.scroll.interpolate({
    inputRange: [0, SCROLL_HEIGHT / 5, SCROLL_HEIGHT],
    outputRange: [THEME_COLOR, FADED_THEME_COLOR, "white"],
    extrapolate: "clamp"
  });
  tabBg = this.scroll.interpolate({
    inputRange: [0, SCROLL_HEIGHT],
    outputRange: ["white", THEME_COLOR],
    extrapolate: "clamp"
  });
  tabY = this.nScroll.interpolate({
    inputRange: [0, SCROLL_HEIGHT, SCROLL_HEIGHT + 1],
    outputRange: [0, 0, 1]
  });
  headerBg = this.scroll.interpolate({
    inputRange: [0, SCROLL_HEIGHT, SCROLL_HEIGHT + 1],
    outputRange: ["transparent", "transparent", THEME_COLOR],
    extrapolate: "clamp"
  });
  imgScale = this.nScroll.interpolate({
    inputRange: [-25, 0],
    outputRange: [1.1, 1],
    extrapolateRight: "clamp"
  });
  imgOpacity = this.nScroll.interpolate({
    inputRange: [0, SCROLL_HEIGHT],
    outputRange: [1, 0],
  });
  tabContent = (x, i) => <View style={{height: this.state.height}}>
    <List onLayout={({nativeEvent: {layout: {height}}}) => {
      this.heights[i] = height;
      if (this.state.activeTab === i) this.setState({height})
    }}>
      {new Array(x).fill(null).map((_, i) => <Item key={i}><Text>Item {i}</Text></Item>)}
    </List></View>;
  heights = [500, 500];
  state = {
    activeTab: 0,
    height: 500
  };

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.nScroll.addListener(Animated.event([{value: this.scroll}], {useNativeDriver: false}));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Animated.View style={{position: "absolute", width: "100%", backgroundColor: this.headerBg, zIndex: 1}}>
          <Header style={{backgroundColor: "transparent"}} hasTabs>
            <Body>
            <Title>
              <Animated.Text style={{color: this.textColor, fontWeight: "bold"}}>
                Tab Parallax
              </Animated.Text>
            </Title>
            </Body>
          </Header>
        </Animated.View>
        <Animated.ScrollView
          scrollEventThrottle={5}
          showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
          onScroll={Animated.event([{nativeEvent: {contentOffset: {y: this.nScroll}}}], {useNativeDriver: true})}
          style={{zIndex: 0}}>
          <Animated.View style={{
            transform: [{translateY: Animated.multiply(this.nScroll, 0.65)}, {scale: this.imgScale}],
            backgroundColor: THEME_COLOR
          }}>
            <Animated.Image
              source={{uri: "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c5/Moraine_Lake_17092005.jpg"}}
              style={{height: IMAGE_HEIGHT, width: "100%", opacity: this.imgOpacity}}>
              {/*gradient*/}
              {/* <LinearGradient
                colors={["rgba(255,255,255,0.9)", "rgba(255,255,255,0.35)", "rgba(255,255,255,0)"]}
                locations={[0, 0.25, 1]}
                style={{position: "absolute", height: "100%", width: "100%"}}/> */}
            </Animated.Image>
          </Animated.View>
          <Tabs
            prerenderingSiblingsNumber={3}
            onChangeTab={({i}) => {
              this.setState({height: this.heights[i], activeTab: i})
            }}
            renderTabBar={(props) => <Animated.View
              style={{transform: [{translateY: this.tabY}], zIndex: 1, width: "100%", backgroundColor: "white"}}>
              <ScrollableTab {...props}
                             renderTab={(name, page, active, onPress, onLayout) => (
                               <TouchableOpacity key={page}
                                                 onPress={() => onPress(page)}
                                                 onLayout={onLayout}
                                                 activeOpacity={0.4}>
                                 <Animated.View
                                   style={{
                                     flex: 1,
                                     height: 100,
                                     backgroundColor: this.tabBg
                                   }}>
                                   <TabHeading scrollable
                                               style={{
                                                 backgroundColor: "transparent",
                                                 width: SCREEN_WIDTH / 2
                                               }}
                                               active={active}>
                                     <Animated.Text style={{
                                       fontWeight: active ? "bold" : "normal",
                                       color: this.textColor,
                                       fontSize: 14
                                     }}>
                                       {name}
                                     </Animated.Text>
                                   </TabHeading>
                                 </Animated.View>
                               </TouchableOpacity>
                             )}
                             underlineStyle={{backgroundColor: this.textColor}}/>
            </Animated.View>
            }>
            <Tab heading="Tab 1">
              {this.tabContent(30, 0)}
            </Tab>
            <Tab heading="Tab 2">
              {this.tabContent(15, 1)}
            </Tab>
          </Tabs>
        </Animated.ScrollView>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

Problems: All screens scrolling because of same offset

4. Fourth is a module [Sticky parallax header](https://github.com/netguru/sticky-parallax-header) you can use tabbed header from here

Problems: Since its module not a lot of room for customization, but there are enough. And also when i was using it there were some issues like all screens scrolling because of same offset which might have been solved now.

So basically speaking all of them have some problems that you will have to solve later on.
But I would recommend the 4th option using the sticky-parallax-header by netguru.

Comment: Thank you very much! a very complete answer. While waiting for an answer I got to point 4 that you explain, and right now I was testing that module. Right now I am fighting a bit because I do not want the header to be displayed until it is scrolled and the tabs touch the top, if you know any solution to that I would appreciate it very much. I would like to vote positively for you but I still do not have the necessary points, still thank you very much :D

Comment: That is fine. And for what you need you will have to raise an issue or edit the module yourself. And by the way, not every prop is given in those examples. So the check the node module content and see if there is something you can use. Sorry that I can't be of much help.